# PageViewController and disable dragging certain view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, gesture, uipageviewcontroller

I have PageViewController with CustomViewControllers as dataSource viewControllers.

The CustomViewControllers contains from 2 views(first on the top half of it and second on the bottom half of it).

If I drag with any of this views, the PageViewController scrolls to another page.
How can I disable dragging it for FirstView ?

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `<UIScrollViewDelegate>` in your .h

Then use the method in .m:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
      yourPageView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
```

Or use these methods and return nil to disable the pageViewController from scrolling:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```